# Using Jquery/MVC/Json to return a Select List to my view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, selectlist

I cannot get this to work no matter how much searching and different variations I keep trying:

I am trying to dynamically populate a select list from my jquery:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("GetCounties", "Account")' + '/' + $("#State").val();
            $.get(url, function (data) {
                $('#county').empty();
                $.each(result, function (index, val) {
                    $('#county')
                    .append($("<option></option>")
                    .attr("value", val.Text)
                    .text(val.Text));
                });
            });
```

Controller Action using Entity Framework:

```
public JsonResult GetCounties(string id)
{
    return Json(GetCountySelectList(id), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

private SelectList GetCountySelectList(string id)
{
    var counties = db.ZipCodeDataBase.Where(x => x.State.Contains(id)).OrderBy(x => x.County).Select(x => x.County).Distinct().ToList();
    SelectList list = new SelectList(counties);
    return list;
}
```

Every variation of the generated select list will not return the data as it is required by the jquery.

Any assistance would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: what's result? did you mean data.d?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling your return variable `data` and then referencing it as `result` in the `$.each`. Try fixing that first.

Comment: That was it! Thank you! I guess I was just looking at it too much today.

Comment: You may wish to delete the question as it isn't a real question anymore.

Comment: No need to delete as it helped me! :) I just saw that I could actually return `SelectListItem` items using `Json`. That's great.